# Where to use generated key to import changesets in "Mantis"

Tags: mantis

Where to use the generated API Key to set up import changesets via shell in mantis bugtracker?

Download or clone a copy of the Source Integration source code.

Copy the primary Source plugin (the Source/ directory) into your Mantis installation's plugins/ directory.

Copy all the remaining plugins, or just the appropriate ones for your repositories, into your Mantis installation's plugins/ directory.

While logged into your Mantis installation as an administrator, go to 'Manage' -> "Manage Plugins".

In the "Available Plugins" list, you'll find the "Source Control Integration" and additional plugins:

a. First, click the "Install" link for the "Source Control Integration" plugin.

b. Next, click the "Install" link next to any additional Source Control plugins appropriate for your repositories.

Click on the "Source Control Integration" plugin to configure it.

NOTE: an **API Key** must be set up to import changesets via shell. To generate a random key, run

openssl rand -hex 12

I followed the above steps but don't know where to use that generated API key to import changesets in Mantis bugtracker

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use an appropriate extension plugin to import changeset. A list of extension plugins are provided in the README file.

For Subversion, the API key should be set in the svn hook script. A sample hook script is available at https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/source-integration/blob/master/SourceSVN/post-commit.tmpl